# Is there any way to set text size as a percentage to the size of the window using CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

Is there a way to style the size of text as a percentage of the ***browser window***? For instance:

```
h1
{
    height: 15%;
    /* in my ideal world this would be 15% of the window 
       (or parent) size rather than inherited font-size */
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CSS3:

```
h1{
   font-size: 15vw; // relative to the viewport's width
   font-size: 15vh; // relative to the viewport's height
   font-size: 15vm; // relative to the ratio width/height of the viewport
}
```

But of course this does not work in all browsers.

Please have a look here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m8VfB/1/ is working in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari. That's a wide swathe of browsers :/

Comment: Do you have any documentation of how well supported this is? I'm just curious. I found [this site](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/vm-vh-units) with a post from August 2011, that seems to indicate not very well supported.

Comment: You are right, this does not seem to work right now. I edited a link to the W3 specification into the post. When I tested this for the first time, it worked. Strange!

Comment: From the post I linked to, IE was the only browser really supporting it. Is that the browser you were working on when it "worked"? I was aware of the spec from W3, just not sure about actual implementation (which does seem to be lacking).

Comment: No, it was probably Chrome. There is also a bug report for chromium, which indicates that it once had been there: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124331

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Although not possible yet but will be in the future.

Answer (score 1):

there is a great jquery solution at http://fittextjs.com/ if you don't mind a little js

Answer (score 0):

This would not be perfect, but using media queries could get close.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 50px) {
  body {
    font-size: 7.5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 100px) {
  body {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 150px) {
  body {
    font-size: 22.5px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-height: 200px) {
  body {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
```

Etc. You would have to determine when to make a "break" point and how far to take it on the low and high end.